# Margrabe option: change of numeraire versus conditioning and numerical integration

Tags: black-scholes, spread-options, margrabes-formula

I am having a slight brain meltdown because I do not seem to be able to understand the following basic thing.

Consider a BS economy, and two assets $X$ and $Y$
$$
dX = \sigma X dW
$$
$$
dY = \nu Y dZ
$$
$$
dWdZ = \rho dt
$$

I would like to price a Margrabe option $(X_T - Y_T)_+$.

The first and most straightforward method is a change of numeraire approach. In other words
$$
E_t(X_T - Y_T)_+ = Y_t E^{Q_Y}( X_T/Y_T -1 )_+
$$
where $Q_Y$ is the measure with $Y$ as numeraire. Now if you evaluate the above expression under this measure you get a relatively simple option price expression, **and where the correlation $\rho$ will appear in the formula**. Agree?

The second approach is to use conditioning. Does everyone agree that I can also price the options as follows:
$$
E_t(X_T - Y_T)_+ = \int_0^\infty C(X_t, y) q(y) dy
$$
where $C(X_t, y)$ is the single asset BS option price with strike $y$, and $q(y)$ is the lognormal distribution of $Y$.

I can always calculate using the numerical integration above right? If so, here is where I am confused: **how does the correlation parameter $\rho$ appear in the numerical integration?** I cannot see it, but it must somehow play a role.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might you be using the tower law in a wrong way? I have the impression you derive your second equation by conditioning by the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $(Y_t)_{t\geq0}$, however note that:
$$\mathscr{F}_t\nsubseteq\sigma(Y_t)_{0\leq t\leq T}$$
Hence:
$$E\left((X_T-Y_T)_+|\mathscr{F}_t\right)\ \not= \ E\left(E(X_T-Y_T)_+|Y_T)|\mathscr{F}_t\right) \ = \ E(C(X_t,Y_T)|\mathscr{F}_t)$$

Comment: Yes I think you are right. What I have to do is split the Brownian motions $W$ and $Z$ into orthogonal components, and then I can use the tower law. So if I write $dZ = \rho dW + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} dW^\bot$, then I can condition on $W^\bot$, agree?

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing to your first observation: After orthogonalization, with independent W and W’, and using self explanatory notation for the new diffusion coefficients, which obviously depend on $\rho$, we can show that, under $\mathbb{Q}_Y$, we have:

$$ dR = R[(\sigma_{XW} - \sigma_{YW})dW + (\sigma_{XW’}  - \sigma_{YW’})dW’], $$

where $R=XY^{-1}$ (used only Ito calculations and the fact that R is a martingale under $\mathbb{Q}_Y$).

Comment: Thank you, yes I understand now. Don't know where I was with my thoughts that I didn't see it (that I had to orthogonalize I mean).